# How can I mirror a root domain to a specific URL in DJANGO and HEROKU?

Tags: django, heroku, dns, cloudflare

I have a Django project deployed in heroku and working fine and also a domain pointing to heroku by cloudflare DNS, which works as well:

> mydomain.com -> myapp.herokuapp.com

***In a simple view, what I want is this:***

> mydomain.com -> myapp.herokuapp.com/page1/

I want to mirror (not redirect) **mydomain.com** to a specific URL of my django project (NOT the root URL). In other words, when user access **mydomain.com** in browser it should see the page **myapp.herokuapp.com/page1/**, but the url must continue to show as **mydomain.com**.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I have had to solve a problem that reminds me of the one you describe. I solved it by making a url request and throwing its content.

```
import requests
from django.http import  HttpResponse

def mirror_topage1(request):
    req = requests.get('myapp.herokuapp.com/page1/')
    r = HttpResponse(req.content)
    return r
```